# Text body (Agenda) updates of a meeting ends up in "delete elements" folder of attendees

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-office, calendar, exchange-2016

I have send an meeting invitation to my colleagues, after a few days I updated some points of meetings agenda, which is found in the text body of the meeting. For all colleagues who had accepted the meeting, the meeting update I send, was found in their "deleted elements" folder. For the colleagues how haven't accept yet, the old invitation was moved to "deleted elements" and the update was found in their inbox.

Is there a way to send agenda updates to all my colleagues (accepted and no response) that reaches their normal inbox?

In [this](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3197165/send-updates-options-for-attendees-are-not-displayed-in-outlook-on-the) article Microsoft differentiated between two categories of meeting updates. In my case the update belongs to the informational update category. The 2nd category is working as expected, if I change the time of a meeting, all colleagues receive the update in their inbox and have to response.

I am glad about answers.
Cheers
John

Answer (score 1):

Maybe [the Set-OrganizationConfig method](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/no-notifications-for-meeting-updates-in-outlook/4b09a273-6da7-40db-ad49-4f295a48a69f) could help you change this phenomenon just as this similar thread describes.